# System error when registering user with first character of the name starts with é

Tags: cakephp, utf-8

I am debugging a registration form.

when a user register a name that stars with é i cannot be save in the system.

I have changed the charset to UTF-8 but it does not work.

the system is running on cakephp framework.

---edit---

Case solved

Comment: Changed the charset where? there's MANY places charsets can be set. The web page, the database connection, the database table collation, etc... Without more details, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: i've changed the charset everywhere.. in the page and database..

Comment: And how does it not work? doesn't record the character? whole thing blows up? something other than an `é` gets recorded?

Comment: if the firstname starts with the é the registration fail. im just wondering why does it happens only if the firstname starts with é.

Comment: fail how? any error messages? ignores the character? changes it to something else?

Comment: It throws the registration error --> "The member could not be saved.
Please check the mandatory field as they are required.
Please, try again."

Comment: You should also SHOW us how you changed it (every single occurrence). then we can tell you what you made wrong. otherwise its just a wild guess